"No IP address found in request" when connecting to local ports
On multiple computers, when I connect localhost:3690 (or any other port, for that matter) or 127.0.0.1:3690 via a browser, or curl, or any other method, I simply get a message that says "No IP address found in request".
Strangely, when I have an express server set up, a red "No IP address found in request" is printed on the backend too.
However, I can connect using my public IP address, or using my domain name. Whether or not Nginx is running, this happens.
Speaking of Nginx, it seems to be working without flaw, even though it is using reverse proxying and multiple different ports.
What I have tried:

Using different IP schemes
Restarting computer
Restarting router
Flushing DNS cache
Turning on / off / restarting Nginx
Using different ports (5173, 6969, etc)
Using an entirely separate computer
Fully disabling firewall

My system:

Nginx
Windows 10
FIOS Router G3100

I need to figure out why these requests aren't working, and how I can fix everything.

What services have you configured on 127.0.0.1; I wouldn’t necessarily expect nginx to be binded on localhost or 127.0.0.1

So I was mentioning Nginx to prove nothing was interfering. By connecting to port 3690 I was expecting to connect to a program using that port but it didn't. Nginx is bound to port 80 which works for some reason.

That makes sense given the use case of Nginx. What services are running on those specific ports?

On 3690 is an express server. But no matter what service I put on the ports I can't connect to it.

You should confirm what Windows is running on the ports via netstat - which I assume is still available on Windows.

Using netstat and currports I can confirm all the ports that aren't working are being used.

It turns out one of my services running in between nginx and express was actually running a logger. The logger throws an exception when I connected from a local port as certain headers were not filled out in the request.

That violates your comment Using netstat and currports I can confirm all the ports that aren't working are being used..

I looked at it and it showed that there were processes listening on the ports.

Then you would have been unable to run another process on that port & device.
